# Navigating a webpage and hiding/showing divs using up down keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to understand the concept of using keys for navigation through a website.

As an exercise, I'm navigate a simple page using only arrow keys. 
So far, I am able to get the keyCodes for up and down keys and catch the event using the following piece of code -

```
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;

function KeyCheck(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

    switch (KeyID) {
        case 38:
            alert("UP");
            break;
        case 40:
            alert("DOWN");
            break;
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3nJL9/1/)

Now I want to navigate through the nav panel on the left using arrow keys to show/hide respective divs on the rightPanel.

Any guidance how can I get this ball rolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this but this came to mind first. You can stack all the divs on the rightPanel on top of each other and have a specific class (ie. hidden) on all except for one of them. As the user presses the 'up' and 'down' button. You can add/remove the hidden class respectively.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
function navigate() {
    switch(key) {
    case up:
        add hidden to current div
        if(not the top) {
            remove hidden from the div above
        } else {
            remove hidden from the last div
        }
        break;
    case down:
        add hidden to current div
        if(not the bottom) {
            remove hidden from the div below
        } else {
            remove hidden from the first div
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Another thing you can do is to turn the rightPanel into a slider that moves up and down instead of left and right. The panel moves up when the user presses up and down when the user presses down.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented what you mentioned in the beginning. Right nav divs are stacked on top of each other. But, I am not sure about how to identify which div to show? for eg. If Lotus is selected, and user clicks 'up' key, the next left nav should be Tulip! How can i catch that in a function?

Comment: What you can do is to store the ids in an array and use an index variable to grab . Another way you can do it is to have this sort of id `flower_1` where an index that is increment or decremented will be appended to `flower_`.